# Why does SoftwareSerial::read() return int?

Tags: softwareserial, hc-06

The documentation on Arduino's website shows `SoftwareSerial::read()` as returning a `char`. ([link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead))

The header shows that the method returns an `int`. ([link](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/7a2e1cd815266fef3012a5c9b48f88d78551f838/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h#L103))

The cpp definition shows `SoftwareSerial::read()` returning the value from a buffer array of `uint8_t` values. ([link](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/7a2e1cd815266fef3012a5c9b48f88d78551f838/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.cpp#L402-L404))

Given all of this:

1. Why would the interface return an `int` instead of a `uint8_t`?
2. Why do the Arduino docs show it as returning a `char`?
3. Is it safe to send/receive 8-bits at a time using this library?

For (3) I'm using an HC-06 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You'll see in the code just above your third link that the function can return a value of `-1` if there is no data present. Thus a 16-bit value is used to cover the range of 8-bit `uint8_t`s, plus one extra value to show 'no valid data available'.
2. For simplicity, I guess.
3. Yes. This is what it's designed for.

In short, for all intents and purposes, only an 8-bit value is returned, but if you were to read into an `int`, you couldn't differentiate between a valid and invalid value.

Comment: Ah awesome! The `-1` value makes sense.

So assuming I gate the `read()` invocation w/ `available()`, it sounds like I can read it into a `uint8_t` directly and work with it as a true byte.

Comment: All the applications I've seen (for all stream type objects) is `if(available()){read();}`. The code you linked to reads the data from the ring buffer into a temporary `uint8_t` before returning into an `int`, so you're not going to lose any data that way

Comment: The actual answer to number 2 is "Because, as in many instances, the Arduino documentation is complete garbage."

Comment: I'm a bit surprised no-one mentioned the fact that it's the exact same reason why [`getchar()` and friends](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) return an `int` in standard C.

Answer (score 4):

> The documentation on Arduino's website shows SoftwareSerial::read() as returning a char.

No it doesn't. There is nothing in the documentation that tells you the return type. There is only an example where the returned value is assigned to a `char` variable. That doesn't mean that it returns a char - it just means that whatever data type it does return can be invisibly cast to a `char` by the compiler.

> The header shows that the method returns an int.

Indeed it does. That is because that is what it returns.

> The cpp definition shows SoftwareSerial::read() returning the value from a buffer array of uint8_t values.

Yes, because the valid data that it deals with is 8 bits in size. Just because it handles 8 bit "valid" data doesn't mean that that's *all* it ever wants to return.  The "no data available" return value of -1 is obviously not something that is stored in the data. It's a status, not data.

---

> Why would the interface return an int instead of a uint8_t?

Because a `uint8_t` cannot encompass all the functionality stated in the "Returns" section:

> the character read, or -1 if none is available

You can't return -1 in a `uint8_t`.

> Why do the Arduino docs show it as returning a char?

It doesn't - as I mentioned above. It makes no claims at all about the returned data type.

> Is it safe to send/receive 8-bits at a time using this library?

Yes. It performs serial data transfers using 8-N-1 by default. That's 8 data bits, no parity, and one stop bit.

---

It's this kind of confusion with return types and bytes and integers and things that make people ask why they keep getting ÿÿÿÿÿÿ on the serial monitor. That's -1 cast as a char. I.e., "no data available" but they ignore that and treat everything returned as a `char` - most probably because the Arduino documentation shows an overly simplified example that ignores the possibility of a -1 being returned and treats everything as a `char`.

IMHO much of the Arduino documentation is somewhat sub-par and should not be taken literally - only as a rough guide for what is available. The same goes for much of their example code and projects.

Comment: There is hope though, as it seems the Arduino documentation is in the process of being refactored. [The documentation for `Serial.read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/), which comes from the new GitHub-hosted ASCII doc-based repository, clearly states “Data type: `int`.” The documentation for `SoftwareSerial` is still in the old format and has presumably not been migrated yet.

Comment: @EdgarBonet That's promising. Maybe they'll do the same with all the bad schematics and example projects...

Answer (score 0):

Stream declares `read` as returning `int` (look in `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Stream.h`). `SofrtwareSerial` inherits from `Stream`, so they have to override that declaration, otherwise there would be two `read()` methods, one returning `int` and one returning `uint8_t`. Since `SoftwareSerial::read()` would onlyreturn an `int` between 0 and 255, which would fit in a `uint8_t`, there is no problem.

As for the Arduino docs, you get what you pay for :)

Comment: many words, no answer. the reason of int is to return -1 meaning "no data to return".